# Mac OS don't have permission to usr/bin folder at all

Tags: macos, permissions

I am trying to rename the "codesign" file name for patch problem, but I tired everything and seems like I can only have read access to the filea inside `usr/bin`

1. Folder permission "System" is set to Read&Write
2. I'm on admin account

What I have tried:
Going into terminal using `sudo -i` to get root access to `usr/bin` for renaming. Typed in renaming command `mv codesign codesign_10.11` still get error of Operation can't be performed

What's wrong with my permission access? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Have you upgraded Mac OS X to the "El Capitan" version?

If so, you can't modify anything in /System, /bin, /sbin, or /usr (except /usr/local) anymore, even using the root user. They are calling this "feature" as "System Integrity Protection".

I had the same problem and found this explanation [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really?newreg=068dc403fea74a3eb1e434b955924023).

Comment: So how does one create a symbolic link to an application now?

Comment: @MikeSchem what exactly you want to do? If you're referring to get a command available on terminal, you can do it by creating a symlink at /usr/local/bin. But if you want to show a .app on Spotlight search, check this question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23653/can-i-make-a-symlink-to-a-app-folder-in-applications-directory-show-up-in-spo).

Comment: yea, I was trying to add a symlink to /usr/local/bin thanks!

Answer (score 3):

execute command line as blow：

sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: a very bad idea to suggest 'sudo' commands without explaining what are you doing.

Answer (score -5):

Try changing the ownership
Code:

```
chown -R "user_name" folder_name
```

Eg:

```
chown -R "John Doe" codesign
```

Comment: Or if your folder is locked see this post [link](http://superuser.com/questions/140769/cant-rename-move-files-from-osx-that-were-copied-from-ntfs)

Comment: Folder is not locked, command not working, same error. chown: codesign: Operation not permitted

Comment: See @Perazzo's reply - Mac OS doesn't allow those base folders to be changed anymore.