# error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/bin/pyobfuscate' MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install pyobfuscate found here: https://github.com/astrand/pyobfuscate on my macOS Sierra using the following command `python setup.py install`but I get the following error:

```
running install
running build
running install_data
copying pyobfuscate -> /usr/bin
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/bin/pyobfuscate'
```

I've tried using `sudo` as well but I get the exact same error.

Comment: you probably don't have write permission to that directory. You could use `sudo` to elevate your privilege.

Comment: @AChampion I've tried using `sudo` as well but same error

Comment: The easy answer is to set up a virtualenv in your home directory so `/usr/bin` isn't being modified.

Comment: See [Mac OS don't have permission to usr/bin folder at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901372/mac-os-dont-have-permission-to-usr-bin-folder-at-all) -- since El Capitan, `/usr/bin` is entirely read-only unless System Integrity Protection is disabled.

Comment: That said, if all `setup.py install` is doing is copying this binary, have you considered copying it somewhere else -- like `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: You could also use `python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just tried this `python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local` and gave the same result

Comment: You still need `sudo` to write to `/usr/local/bin`. Unless by "the same result" you mean it said it was trying to write to `/usr/bin/pyobfuscate` instead of `/usr/local/bin/pyobfuscate`.

Comment: (That kind of ambiguity is why saying "the same result" is much less useful than a log of the *exact* output).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry. Yes, I tried with `sudo` but it tries to write in `/usr/bin/pyobfuscate` instead of `/usr/local/bin/pyobfuscate`

Comment: Okay, *that's* helpful. I'll want to look at the `setup.py` for that specific program. Unfortunately, I'm being called to dinner right now.

Comment: (You might try the virtualenv route while I'm away).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142556/discussion-between-tak-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no worries, enjoy your dinner. I've tried using virtualenv as shown here http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ and then I have this in my terminal  `(pyobfuscateVirtual) UserA-MBP:pyobfuscate usera` and once I run this `$ sudo python setup.py install` I get the same error.

Comment: Back from dinner, joining the chat. :)

Comment: Filed this as https://github.com/astrand/pyobfuscate/issues/19, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In general: Avoid `/usr/bin` on current MacOS (where it's read-only)

`/usr/bin` isn't writable on new versions of MacOS, even as root, unless System Integrity Protection has been disabled. Consider:

```
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

Another option, which doesn't require `sudo` at all, is to use a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv ~/pyobfuscate.venv     ## create a virtualenv
. ~/pyobfuscate.venv/bin/activate ## activate that virtualenv
python setup.py install           ## install pyobfuscate in that virtualenv
```

...and thereafter, `. ~/pyobfuscate.venv/bin/activate` in a given shell before running `pyobfuscate` in that shell.

---

#### But pyobfuscate's `setup.py` needs to be fixed before you can do that:

That said, current versions of pyobfuscate have their `setup.py` written as follows:

```
data_files=[('/usr/bin', ['pyobfuscate'])]
```

That's inappropriate, and instead, should be:

```
scripts=['pyobfuscate']
```

...which will follow the prefix given, whether via a virtualenv or a `--prefix=` argument.

Comment: I tried with `sudo` but didn't work as it tries to write in `/usr/bin/pyobfuscate` instead of `/usr/local/bin/pyobfuscate`

Comment: Ahh. Reading the `setup.py`, I see why it wasn't working -- answer edited appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ***setup.py*** replace

```
data_files=[('/usr/bin', ['pyobfuscate'])]
```

with

```
scripts=['pyobfuscate']
```