# vagrant share ngrok rescue in execute': No such file or directory

Tags: vagrant, ngrok

I'm trying to get vagrant share working , it's been a while I used to use it without ngrok no problem on an older version / project I have a ngrok account installed the auth token logged into my vagrant cloud when running vagrant share getting error, any help greatly appreciated

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.7/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:146:in `rescue in execute': No such file or directory - ngrok (Vagrant::Util::Subprocess::LaunchError)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.7/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:139:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.9/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:2451:in `block in start_ngrok_proxy'
```

Comment: I guess I don't need vagrant share it works fine just using ngrok

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too. This may only be applicable to Macs but here's how I solved it.

First you need to have ngrok installed on your computer.

After you're certain it is installed, there should be a script called ngrok in the directory where you unzipped the download folder during installation.

All I did was add the path to the ngrok script to my PATH on my Mac and after that, `vagrant share` worked fine.

Here's a blog about how to add a file to the PATH on a Mac. https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.WdaTyxNSx-U

Answer (score 1):

There's another option and probably a cleaner one : 
Copy the ngrok executable to your /usr/local/bin which is invented to hold custom executables and reside in the /etc/paths

More info : 
[Mac OS don't have permission to usr/bin folder at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901372/mac-os-dont-have-permission-to-usr-bin-folder-at-all)

Editing the /etc/paths might open unintentional access to other executables